# Oracle SELECT for UPDATE locking without any DML

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

At work, I noticed something odd. Records in about 10 tables are locked and only records from 4 fo 10 tables were actually updated/deleted. Could there be any purpose to locking records using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` without actually doing any DML operations? Would it not be a waste to lock the remaining 6 tables?

Comment: Probably other 6 tables are locked to ensure a business transaction consistency while only updating 4 tables.

Comment: Oracle will lock all records involved in your query unless you specify your locking in the `UPDATE FOR` portion of your query. Perhaps you could provide the query you are running.

Comment: @gmiley. Incorrect. Oracle will lock *no* rows in a query, unless you specify  'FOR UPDATE'.

Comment: @BobC - that's what I said. Granted, I wasn't paying attention when I typed `FOR UPDATE` and swapped the word order, but what I said is that `FOR UPDATE` causes rows to lock. What I was also conveying is that you can narrow your locking by specifying a narrower locking scope in your query.